# Json.NET does not use JsonProperty on deserialize

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, json.net, json-deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize the following json

```
{
   "category": "mycategory",
   "updated_date": "2011-11-10T03:07:43",
   "description":"description",
   "image": "someImageUrl",
   "longitude": 100,
   "latitude": 100,
   "state": 1,
   "user": "Mike",
   "created_date": "2011-11-10T03:07:43",
   "active": true,
   "id": 1,
   "resource_uri": "something"
}
```

into the object

```
public class Report
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "category")]
        public object Category { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "updated_date")]
        public string UpdatedDate { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "longitude")]
        public double Longitude { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "latitude")]
        public double Latitude { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "state")]
        public int State { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "user")]
        public object User { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "created_date")]
        public string CreatedDate { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "active")]
        public bool Active { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "resource_uri")]
        public string ResourceURI { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "image")]
        public string Image { get; set; }
    }
```

If i use something direct like

```
Report result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Report>(data);
```

it work fine and all properties deserializes as they should.

But if I try to use this class in REST WEB API it starts act weird. Serialization works just fine? but deserialization fails: all three properties with "_" in their PropertyName do not deserialize. They are always null.
As I understand it is something in settings and configurations, but I cannot figure out what exactly.

**EDIT:**
JS Code

```
$.ajax(uri,
type:'PUT',
data: {
  category: "someCategory",
  updated_date: "2012-11-10T03:07:43",
  description: "desc3",
  image: "someImgaeUrl",
  longitude: 10,
  latitude: 20,
  state: 1,
  user: "Mike",
  created_date: "2010-11-10T03:07:43",
  active: false,
  id: 0,
  resource_uri: "somethring"
})
```

C# Code:

```
[Route("{id}")]
[HttpPut]
public HttpResponseMessage Report(int id, [FromBody]ReportModel report)
{ //Do Something}
```

Comment: This could be something tricky like a bug. You may receive better response at http://json.codeplex.com/discussions. As an experiment, remove the `JsonProperty` attribute and name the field according to the JSON object, if that works, then the attribute may not be handled appropriately.

Comment: Please post the code you ouse to POST to the Rest Web API and the corresponding Web API method to handle it.

Comment: If names are equal (plus minus letter case) it works fine. Added code

Comment: Try changing your C# class because I believe that hyphones are parsed into underscores.

Comment: I'm guessing this is a bug and is still an issue 2 years later. In my case, I needed to take JSON properties with spaces and map to C# property names that obviously can't have spaces.

Comment: is it the same i you stringify the data in the client before sending the object?

Comment: I'm having the same issue using durable functions, and none of my properties have underscores, just all lowercase letters rather than camel case as per normal .Net class property name recommendations